# Out of memory error persisting when I free up memory, with barely and documentation

Tags: java, android, memory, andengine

I get the error

```
<ioct1_kgsl_sharedmem_alloc:1480>: ioct1_kgsl_sharedmem_alloc: FATAL ERROR : (null)
```

in my game when about 4~5 scenes have been created. I understand that it has to do with memory, but there is barely anything on it online, and I created two methods two remove all the sprites and bodies of the scene, but the error persists. I don't know why it's giving me the error when I create about four or five scenes regardless of whether or not I clear sprites and bodies from the previous scene.

Comment: Are you sure it has to do with memory? The "null" after "fatal error" seems surprising.

Comment: Post you code where you create objects, especially the part where you are creating textures.

Comment: Possible duplicate of this:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19346967/completely-remove-scene-in-andengine
Stick with your existing question so you don't fragment the replies of people trying to help you.